# Add serial Number in MySQL join query

Tags: mysql

I saw many answer to add serial number to a simple table, but here i want to add serial key to a join query. I tried this query

```
SELECT  *,@c:=@c+1 AS serialNumber 
FROM 
(SELECT @c:= 0) AS c,
(
  SELECT a.ai_id,a.ai_images,a.user_id,a.ai_like_count,a.ai_comment_count,a.ai_caption,u.display_name,u.first_name,u.email,a.ai_created 
  FROM album_images AS a 
  LEFT JOIN users AS u 
  ON a.user_id=u.user_id 
  WHERE u.email_validation=1 
  AND u.status=1 
  ORDER BY a.ai_created DESC
) AS t 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY ai_created DESC
```

But I'm not getting number in a proper order it's getting like `1,5,8` like this. I want it like this `1,2,3,4`

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.  It is not quite clear what you want.  You are also using `select` with columns not included in the `group by` clause.  MySQL explicit warns against this.

Comment: those are very big tables and hard to describe, if you can please tell me how to add serial numbers to any basic joining query?

Comment: Put the `group by` in a subquery.  Then add the number in the outer query.  I cannot condone your code, because you are misusing `group by`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
 set @c=0;
 SELECT @c:=@c+1 AS serialNumber,tab.* 
 FROM (
 SELECT * FROM
  (
   SELECT     a.ai_id,a.ai_images,a.user_id,a.ai_like_count,a.ai_comment_count,a.ai_caption,u.display_name,u.first_name,u.email,a.ai_created 
   FROM album_images AS a 
   LEFT JOIN users AS u ON a.user_id=u.user_id 
   WHERE u.email_validation=1 AND u.status=1 ORDER BY a.ai_created DESC) AS t GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY ai_created DESC
) AS tab
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the answer from this query

Answer (score 0):

After assigning serial number, you are ordering the result-set by `ai_created` which causes the issue. Use ordering in inner query. This is example:

```
SELECT  *,@c:=@c+1 AS serialNumber 
    FROM 
    (SELECT @c:= 0) AS c,
    (
      SELECT a.ai_id,a.ai_images,a.user_id,a.ai_like_count,a.ai_comment_count,a.ai_caption,u.display_name,u.first_name,u.email,a.ai_created 
      FROM album_images AS a 
      LEFT JOIN users AS u 
      ON a.user_id=u.user_id 
      WHERE u.email_validation=1 
      AND u.status=1 
      GROUP BY a.user_id 
      ORDER BY a.ai_created DESC
    ) AS t
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, am getting the serial number correctly, but the answer is changed, am not getting the answer what i want.

Comment: @BasilPJoy : use filter as per your requirement or you can put the whole query in the sub-query keeping serial in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Serial Number (SL) can be added to the Query with UNION operation. Here is example, for the Report of KOHA ILS:

```
enter code here:  SELECT  @c:=@c+1 AS 'SL' , t.* 
FROM 
(SELECT @c:= 0 AS cc) AS c,
(
SELECT biblio.biblionumber AS BiblioNumber,
GROUP_CONCAT(items.barcode  ORDER BY items.barcode SEPARATOR ',\r\n') AS 'Accession #', 
biblio.title AS Title, 
biblio.author AS 'Main Author',  
COUNT(items.barcode) AS Qty, 
SUM(items.price) AS 'Price (Tk.)', 
@bill_number :=items.stocknumber AS 'Bill No.' FROM biblio LEFT JOIN items ON ( biblio.biblionumber = items.biblionumber ) 
WHERE 
items.stocknumber =  <<Bill Number>>
GROUP BY biblio.biblionumber
) AS t UNION 
SELECT '','','','','','<b>Grand Total:</b>', SUM(items.price),'' FROM items WHERE items.stocknumber LIKE @bill_number GROUP BY items.stocknumber UNION SELECT '','','','','','<b>Net Payable Amount:</b>', @grand_total:=SUM(items.price),'' FROM items WHERE items.stocknumber LIKE @bill_number  GROUP BY items.stocknumber UNION SELECT '','','<b>Amount Chargeable:</b>', CONCAT("<b>(In Word)"," Tk. ", number_to_words(@grand_total),"Only </b>"),'', '', '',''  UNION
SELECT '','','<b>Print Date-Time:</b>', CONCAT("<b>",NOW(),"</b>"),'', '', '','';
```